# Issue with ngDialog - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have installed in my project the ngDialog module using *bower install ng-dialog*. I can verify that this is installed by checking my bower.json file.

```
         {
          "name": "larissaApp",
          "description": "Municipality of Larissa",
          "main": "index.html",
          "keywords": [
            "larissa",
            "Greece",
            "History"
          ],
          "authors": [
            "Theo Tziomakas"
          ],
          "license": "MIT",
          "homepage": "",
          "ignore": [
            "**/.*",
            "node_modules",
            "bower_components",
            "test",
            "tests"
          ],
          "dependencies": {
            "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "ng-dialog": "^1.3.0"
          }
        }
```

However,when I am running my project I am getting this error

```
Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider <- ngDialog <- HeaderController
```

I don't understand that,as I include all files in my index.html file.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" ng-app="larissaApp">

            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
                     content must come *after* these tags -->

                <title>Municipality of Larissa</title>    

            <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
                <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="bower_components/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="bower_components/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog-theme-plain.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="bower_components/ng-dialog/css/ngDialog-theme-default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- endbuild -->

                <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
            </head>

            <body>


                <div ui-view="header"></div>
                <div ui-view="content"></div>
                <div ui-view="footer"></div>



            <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
                <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
                <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
                <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"
                  ></script>
                <script src="bower_components/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
            <!-- endbuild -->

            </body>

            </html>
```

Why is this happening? All the ng-files are inside my bower_components folder.

My controller is shown below.

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('larissaApp')
    .controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', 'ngDialog', 'AuthFactory', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope, ngDialog, AuthFactory) {

        $scope.loggedIn = false;
        $scope.username = '';

        if(AuthFactory.isAuthenticated()) {
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
            $scope.username = AuthFactory.getUsername();
        }

        $scope.openLogin = function () {
            ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/login.html', scope: $scope, className: 'ngdialog-theme-default', controller:"LoginController" });
        };

        $scope.logOut = function() {
           AuthFactory.logout();
            $scope.loggedIn = false;
            $scope.username = '';
        };

        $rootScope.$on('login:Successful', function () {
            $scope.loggedIn = AuthFactory.isAuthenticated();
            $scope.username = AuthFactory.getUsername();
        });

        $rootScope.$on('registration:Successful', function () {
            $scope.loggedIn = AuthFactory.isAuthenticated();
            $scope.username = AuthFactory.getUsername();
        });

        $scope.stateis = function(curstate) {
           return $state.is(curstate);  
        };

    }])

    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', '$localStorage', 'AuthFactory', function ($scope, ngDialog, $localStorage, AuthFactory) {

        $scope.loginData = $localStorage.getObject('userinfo','{}');

        $scope.doLogin = function() {
            if($scope.rememberMe)
               $localStorage.storeObject('userinfo',$scope.loginData);

            AuthFactory.login($scope.loginData);

            ngDialog.close();

        };

        $scope.openRegister = function () {
            ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/register.html', scope: $scope, className: 'ngdialog-theme-default', controller:"RegisterController" });
        };

    }])

    .controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', '$localStorage', 'AuthFactory', function ($scope, ngDialog, $localStorage, AuthFactory) {

        $scope.register={};
        $scope.loginData={};

        $scope.doRegister = function() {
            console.log('Doing registration', $scope.registration);

            AuthFactory.register($scope.registration);

            ngDialog.close();

        };
    }])
    ;
```

and my services.js

```
        'use strict';

        angular.module('larissaApp')
        .constant('baseURL', 'http://localhost:3000/')
        .factory('AuthFactory', ['$resource', '$http', '$localStorage', '$rootScope', '$window', 'baseURL', 'ngDialog', function($resource, $http, $localStorage, $rootScope, $window, baseURL, ngDialog){

            var authFac = {};
            var TOKEN_KEY = 'Token';
            var isAuthenticated = false;
            var username = '';
            var authToken = undefined;


          function loadUserCredentials() {
            var credentials = $localStorage.getObject(TOKEN_KEY,'{}');
            if (credentials.username != undefined) {
              useCredentials(credentials);
            }
          }

          function storeUserCredentials(credentials) {
            $localStorage.storeObject(TOKEN_KEY, credentials);
            useCredentials(credentials);
          }

          function useCredentials(credentials) {
            isAuthenticated = true;
            username = credentials.username;
            authToken = credentials.token;

            // Set the token as header for your requests!
            $http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = authToken;
          }

          function destroyUserCredentials() {
            authToken = undefined;
            username = '';
            isAuthenticated = false;
            $http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = authToken;
            $localStorage.remove(TOKEN_KEY);
          }

            authFac.login = function(loginData) {

                $resource(baseURL + "users/login")
                .save(loginData,
                   function(response) {
                      storeUserCredentials({username:loginData.username, token: response.token});
                      $rootScope.$broadcast('login:Successful');
                   },
                   function(response){
                      isAuthenticated = false;

                      var message = '\
                        <div class="ngdialog-message">\
                        <div><h3>Login Unsuccessful</h3></div>' +
                          '<div><p>' +  response.data.err.message + '</p><p>' +
                            response.data.err.name + '</p></div>' +
                        '<div class="ngdialog-buttons">\
                            <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click=confirm("OK")>OK</button>\
                        </div>'

                        ngDialog.openConfirm({ template: message, plain: 'true'});
                   }

                );

            };

            authFac.logout = function() {
                $resource(baseURL + "users/logout").get(function(response){
                });
                destroyUserCredentials();
            };

            authFac.register = function(registerData) {

                $resource(baseURL + "users/register")
                .save(registerData,
                   function(response) {
                      authFac.login({username:registerData.username, password:registerData.password});
                    if (registerData.rememberMe) {
                        $localStorage.storeObject('userinfo',
                            {username:registerData.username, password:registerData.password});
                    }

                      $rootScope.$broadcast('registration:Successful');
                   },
                   function(response){

                      var message = '\
                        <div class="ngdialog-message">\
                        <div><h3>Registration Unsuccessful</h3></div>' +
                          '<div><p>' +  response.data.err.message + 
                          '</p><p>' + response.data.err.name + '</p></div>';

                        ngDialog.openConfirm({ template: message, plain: 'true'});

                   }

                );
            };

            authFac.isAuthenticated = function() {
                return isAuthenticated;
            };

            authFac.getUsername = function() {
                return username;  
            };

            loadUserCredentials();

            return authFac;

        }]);
```

Here is my app.js. I added the ng-dialog module.

```
'use strict';

            angular.module('larissaApp', ['ui.router','ngResource','ngDialog'])
            .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                    $stateProvider

                        // route for the home page
                        .state('app', {
                            url:'/',
                            views: {
                                'header': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/header.html',
                                    controller  : 'HeaderController'
                                },
                                'content': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
                                    controller  : 'HomeController'
                                },
                                'footer': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/footer.html',
                                }
                            }

                        })
                        // route for the contactus page
                        .state('app.city', {
                            url:'city',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/city.html',
                                    controller  : 'CityController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })

                        .state('app.administration', {
                            url:'administration',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/administration.html',
                                    controller  : 'ΑdministrationController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        // route for the contactus page
                        .state('app.contactus', {
                            url:'contactus',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/contactus.html',
                                    controller  : 'ContactController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })

                        // route for the contactus page
                        .state('app.alcazar-park', {
                            url:'alcazar-park',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/alcazar-park.html',
                                    controller  : 'ΑlcazarParκController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .state('app.first_ancient_theatre', {
                            url:'first_ancient_theatre',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/first_ancient_theatre.html',
                                    controller  : 'FirstAncientTheatreController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .state('app.second_ancient_theatre', {
                            url:'second_ancient_theatre',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/second_ancient_theatre.html',
                                    controller  : 'SecondAncientTheatreController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .state('app.bezesteni', {
                            url:'bezesteni',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/bezesteni.html',
                                    controller  : 'BezesteniController'                  
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .state('app.basilica', {
                                url:'basilica',
                                views: {
                                    'content@': {
                                        templateUrl : 'views/basilica.html',
                                        controller  : 'BasilicaController'                  
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        .state('app.mill_of_pappas', {
                                url:'mill_of_pappas',
                                views: {
                                    'content@': {
                                        templateUrl : 'views/mill_of_pappas.html',
                                        controller  : 'MillController'                  
                                    }
                                }
                        })
                        .state('app.church', {
                                url:'church',
                                views: {
                                    'content@': {
                                        templateUrl : 'views/church.html',
                                        controller  : 'ChurchController'                  
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        // route for the newsdetails page
                        .state('app.newsdetails', {
                            url: 'newsdetails/:id',
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl : 'views/newsdetails.html',
                                    controller  : 'NewsDetailsController'
                               }
                            }
                        });;




                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
                })
            ;
```

But now I get this error.

```
Failed to instantiate module larissaApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
at 

http://127.0.0.1:56710/larissaApp/public/bower_components/angular
/angular.min.js:6:425
at http://127.0.0.1:56710/larissaApp/public/bower_components/angular
/angular.min.js:42:407
```

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: share your angularjs code.. how you instantiate your module..

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, you still haven't added the module init code.. it would have dependencies listed in `[]`next to `angular.module('...',`

Comment: Can you please post your app.js as well? You might have forgotten angular module dependency. It is something like this
angular.module('larissaApp', ['ngDialog'])

Comment: I added as well the app.js file in the question.

Comment: Everything looks fine right now, can you change your angular.min.js to angular.js? It might give more detailed error.